# Can I use Spring Batch Admin into Spring-Boot 2.2.2 (latest)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch-admin

I'm working with spring-batch project.
And I added Dependency like below.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-admin-manager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Batch Integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

My project name is "batch". So I tried to access "http://localhost:8080/batch/"

But I cannot access to Admin Page.
Can someone tell me how to integrate spring-batch-admin to spring-boot project?
I also read this article.
https://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-batch-admin-tutorial/

Comment: spring batch admin console is end of life see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/trunk/.

Comment: @FredvN thanks for your comment. So there is no way to see the admin pages? I aslo heard https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow is the alternatives. but dataflow is too heavy for me.